# Android Studio Kotlin redeclaration error with actual/expect

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, multiplatform, redeclaration

Android Studio reports a redeclaration error with Kotlin objects even though Gradle builds the project correctly.

I have this in my commonMain

```
expect object ApplicationConfig {
    val url1: String
    val url2: String
    val url3: String
}
```

I have source sets commonMain, androidBase, commonDevelopment, commonStaging, commonRelease, androidDevelopment, androidStaging and androidRelease.

commonMain declares an expect object for application settings. commonDevelopment, commonStaging and commonRelease declare the actual objects with build specific settings. I am hoping to reuse these for Android and iOS builds.

androidDevelopment, androidStaging and androidRelease depend on the corresponding source sets commonXXXX and source set androidBase.

```
sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies { ... }
    }
    val androidBase by creating {
        dependencies { ... }
    }

    val commonDevelopment by creating {
        dependsOn(commonMain)
    }

    val commonRelease by creating {
        dependsOn(commonMain)
    }

    val commonStaging by creating {
        dependsOn(commonMain)
    }

    val androidRelease by getting {
        dependsOn(commonRelease)
        dependsOn(androidBase)
    }

    val androidStaging by creating {
        dependsOn(commonStaging)
        dependsOn(androidBase)
    }

    val androidDevelopment by creating {
        dependsOn(commonDevelopment)
        dependsOn(androidBase)
    }
}
```

[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMeqM.png)

I have the following build types:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release")
        create("staging") {
            isJniDebuggable = true
        }
        create("development") {
            isDefault = true
            isJniDebuggable = true
        }
    }
...
}
```

Gradle seems to understand that only one source set with the actual object is included, but Android Studio doesn't detect this. I do not need product flavors. Build types are sufficient. I want to reuse these settings classes for Android and iOS.

Am I misusing the expect/actual mechanism and build types or is this just a bug in Android Studio?

I have these settings:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2")
    }
```

And

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
```

Comment: I searched redeclaration issues and I found comments that a class or object should be included in all source sets except in the common main one. According to the documentation it something related to build types or flavors. I couldn't figure this out. I tried removing the expect object from commonMain, but it didn't work. Also, it would not help as I need the expect object available in the common source set.

Comment: I have Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2 with Kotlin plugin version 211-1.6.20-release-275-AS7442.40